# Xamarin App mode Release no found conexion sql

Tags: xamarin

develop an app that contains a connection to a database in sql, in debug mode it works correctly, but in release mode it does not load the SQL data. Already try putting internet permissions in the manifest. Help!!

Comment: Where is the relevant code and error messages?  There is not useful information here we could use to help you.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to disable [Linker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos).
If something works in Debug mode but does not in Release mode then most likely the issue is that the Linker is not including your dll when it generates the Release binary.

you could right click your Android project,then **Properties** -> **Android Options** -> **Linking** -> **None**

If you select "Don't Link" all dlls your project reference will be include in the Release binary. This will lead to a larger binary size but will help you diagnose if this it the problem.

Comment: @DavidNicolasGomez could you show the error message of the output ?